# Is there any difference between "for one's birthday" or "on one's birthday"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell please if there is the slightest difference between the following questions?

> What did you get **for** your last birthday?
>
> What did you get **on** your last birthday?

If there is no difference at all, which one do you think is more common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For your birthday* = as a birthday present, or to celebrate.

*On your birthday* = on that day.

The first of your sentences would be the normal way to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Google Ngram Viewer shows no results at all for 'get on your last birthday' or even 'get on your birthday'.

"On your birthday" means the exact day. "For your birthday" means that's the reason. You might get all your presents on the exact day, but if your birthday is on a Saturday or Sunday this year, people (at work, for example) might give you a present on the Friday or Monday, or you might receive some in the post sometime sooner or later.